# Auto-create PNGs from Visio files

Tags: powershell, automation, office-automation

I work regularly in Visio to make diagrams/charts/etc. and need to export them to PNG for the rest of my team to consume. Doing this manually starts to become a problem as charts are continuously updated.

What I want is that everytime the visio file is changed, the exported PNGs are updated to a new version automatically. How do I do that?

Comment: Look for method Export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micky is correct, there is an export Com Method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427146%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that you can use. However, what you really want is like a filewatcher to notice whenever a file is modified?

That's kind of a separate question, so I'll focus this answer on just how to export out a visio document as a PNG file.

```
$visioApp = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$visioApp.visible = $false
[void]$visioApp.Documents.Add("C:\temp\drawing1.vsdx")
foreach($page in $visioApp.ActiveDocument.Pages) {
   $page.Export("C:\temp\$($page.name).png")
}
```

To export out whenever the file change you'd need to use filewatcher, one of the Com events on document changing available in the namespace, or just have a scheduled task that iterated through a directory and exported them out on a given schedule.

Comment: Just wanted to add that some other versions of the code above use $visioApp.Documents.Open instead of Documents.Add. Open could mess up if you already have that file open in another window (or it's otherwise locked), but Add seems to work great.